# Read timeout Error in Net::HTTP live.t test in Perl 5.32

Tags: perl

Something seems broken related to Perl module Net::HTTP. I'm running in a Docker container whose image is being built with:

```
RUN curl -SL https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz -o /opt/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvzf /opt/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz --directory /opt \
    && cd /opt/perl-5.32.1 \
    && ./Configure -de \
    && make \
    && make test \
    && make install \
    && rm -f /opt/perl-5.32.1.tar.gz \
    && yes | cpan install App::cpanminus \
    && yum install -y openssl \
    && cpanm install OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.55.tar.gz \
    && cpanm install OALDERS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.10.tar.gz \
    && rm -Rf /opt/perl-5.32.1
```

When it gets to the libwww-perl installation, it fails because one of the tests in the Net::HTTP installation failed. (It completes without error if I add `&& cpanm install -f Net::HTTP \` above that line).

With some fiddling around I produced this script:

```
use Net::HTTP;
my $s = Net::HTTP->new(Host => "www.neverssl.com", KeepAlive => 1, Timeout => 15, PeerHTTPVersion => "1.1", MaxLineLength => 512) || die "$@";
for my $iter (1..2) {
   $s->write_request(GET => "/",, 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept-Language' => 'no,en', Accept => '*/*');
   print "Reading response for request $iter.\n";
   my ($code, $mess, %h) = $s->read_response_headers;
   print "# --------------------\n";
   print "# $code $mess\n";
   my $buf;
   while (1) {
      my $n = $s->read_entity_body($tmp, 20);
      last unless $n;
      $buf .= $tmp;
   }
   $buf =~ s/\r//g;
   print "Request $iter completed.\n";
}
```

It produces this output in the problem docker environment:

```
Reading response for request 1.
# --------------------
# 200 OK
Request 1 completed.
Reading response for request 2.
read timeout at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.32.1/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 274.
```

When I run the same script on my main desktop it runs to completion without error.
`perl -version` on my desktop reports:
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

`cpan -D Net::HTTP` on my desktop reports:

```
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.217)
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.67)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.81)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Database was generated on Thu, 23 Feb 2023 22:07:26 GMT
Updating database file ... Done!
Net::HTTP
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20200314)
(no description)
        O/OA/OALDERS/Net-HTTP-6.22.tar.gz
        C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Net\HTTP.pm
        Installed: 6.22
        CPAN:      6.22  up to date
        Olaf Alders (OALDERS)
        olaf@wundersolutions.com
```

The test still succeeds on my desktop after running this cpan command.

How do I further narrow down the source of or fix this error or confirm it's a know issue?

Comment: strace -s2000 -f command... or tcpdump -i interface -n -s2000 (or Wireshark instead) to see what's going on there. I expect some wrong server-side implementation of HTTP KeepAlive when it fails only on 2nd request.